# Machine learning prediction considering several variables, is that possible?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, factors

I have a project where I have to predict a label (whether that's suitable for that situation or not) considering several variables.

e.g., Imagine a mango market where the price of mango goes high at 12 pm but gradually goes down after that or vice versa. Mangoes can be of different colors and sizes (attributes of the mangoes if those are properly ripened or not). Someone wants to buy mangoes from that market. What time and which color or what size will be the best choice for that person(considering different factors)?

I have done a small classification project with boosted regression tree and the result of classification is awesome. But, I can't seem to figure out how to make the algorithm decide which is the better choice (rather than only classification)

Any kind of idea will be highly appreciated. If my question is kinda dumb, I'm sorry for that :( and thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions; questions about general data science methodology are off-topic here, and should be posted at [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, and it should be posted at [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.